# Selecting the right button with iMacros

Tags: imacros

I just started to use iMacros in Chrome to help me carrying out a quite tedious tasks. I have a website with a long list of codes and need to click several times for each number. My script looks as follows:

```
VERSION BUILD=844 RECORDER=CR

URL GOTO=https://bimxtra.com/Programming/WBSDiscipline.aspx
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 10 
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:t-font-icon<SP>rgIcon<SP>rgEditIcon&&TXT:
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG POS=154 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:f1 ATTR=* CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=155 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:f1 ATTR=* CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=156 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:f1 ATTR=* CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=157 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:f1 ATTR=* CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=158 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:f1 ATTR=* CONTENT=YES
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:ctl00_p1_RadTreeList1_ctl00_ctl*_EditForm_btnUpdateTop&&TXT:Update
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 6
```

My problem comes when I try to click the "Update"buttom on the righ top corner of the attached image.
[capture of the website where I need to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDuBN.png)

In the image can be seen a number of boxes that I need to tick before I click on "Update"

This is the ID of the bottom

TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:ctl00_p1_RadTreeList1_ctl00_ctl*_EditForm_btnUpdateTop&&TXT:Update

but the ID of the "Cancel" button is really similar, in fact it seems to be embeded within the same button:

TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:ctl00_p1_RadTreeList1_ctl00_ctl*_EditForm_btnCancelTop

For some reason the script works fine but then it clicks on Cancel and therefore the changes are not saved. I tried adding another parameter to identify the right one using && TEXT:Update as it can be seen in my script but still no luck.

I would appreciate if anyone has any answer to this.

Thanks,

Jaime

Comment: Btw, I have tested the macro to work without looping it (changed the {{!LOOP}} for an actual value) and it does the job without problems

Comment: Perhaps you just have to remove the line `URL GOTO=https://bimxtra.com/Programming/WBSDiscipline.aspx` from your macro.

Comment: I just switched from Chrome to Firefox and it seems to work better now.